# Is there any notification channel in azure-devops just for my project?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have been searching for a notification channel in Azure Devops. Notification can be when a release happens, I want to send a custom mail to all the team members or when someone is working on some pipeline changes I want to display a message to the team members saying they might expect disruptions in using that pipeline. I saw message banners on top, which are organization wide and not for an individual project.

Any leads on a better notification channel?

Answer (score 0):

In the Project Seetings, there's a Notifications setting which should be the one you are looking for.

You can see the usement in the doc [Manage notifications for a team or group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-team-group-notifications?view=azure-devops).

This allows you to custom your notifications when it should be sent and who would recieve the notifications.

You can set filter to a specific project when you create a custom notification:

[image]

Comment: But I cannot customize the content of the notification. This is for a defined set of trigger actions like a build is completed or a release is failed. But if I want to customize the notification I don't see any option. If I need a notification banner just for my project, there is no provision. This notification message banner on top is a good way but it is organization wide.

Comment: Yes, it can not be customized. In fact there's no such available build in function in Azure DevOps Service. But there's a user voice you can follow [Customise VSTS email templates](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365760/customise-vsts-email-templates.html).